# How to do operation on an output tables in sql or php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have these tables

```
courses                                students_records 
---------------------               --------------------------------  
NO      code     CRD                name       ID      NO    grade
---------------------               --------------------------------
1      COE200     4                 Michael   2255      1      A
2      COE305     3                 Michael   2255      2      B+


grades
---------------------               
NO.     points
---------------------               
A        4                 
B+      3.5
```

I wrote this query

```
     SELECT courses.code,student_records.grade,courses.crd,grades.points  FROM grades INNER
     JOIN student_records ON grades.letter = student_records.grade INNER
 JOIN courses ON courses.no = student_records.no WHERE student_records.id=2255;
```

so the out put of this query will be like this

```
grades
------------------------------             
code     grade   CRD    points
------------------------------               
COE200    A       4       4            
COE305    B+      3       3.5
```

My question is How I can write function in php or query in order to 
multiply CRD and points and do sum after multiply like this.

```
(CRD * points)
 (4*4)+(3*3.5)=26.5
```

Comment: if we do it in mysql you will lose the information from one row, is that okay? otherwise you'd have to do it in php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform the math in the SQL Select and an aggregation to do the sum.

To get the grade/credits to show, you can use this query:

```
SELECT 
    courses.code,
    student_records.grade,
    courses.crd,grades.points, 
    courses.crd * grades.points AS grade_credits
FROM grades 
    INNER JOIN student_records ON grades.letter = student_records.grade
    INNER JOIN courses ON courses.no = student_records.no 
WHERE student_records.id=2255;
```

For the sum, you can use most of the same query:

```
SELECT 
    student_records.id,
    SUM(courses.crd * grades.points) AS sum_grade_credits
FROM grades 
    INNER JOIN student_records ON grades.letter = student_records.grade
    INNER JOIN courses ON courses.no = student_records.no 
GROUP BY student_records.id
```

This would give you results for all students.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would do it in PHP:

```
$totalgrade = 0;
while($row = $query->fetch_array()) {
    $totalgrade += $row['CRD']*$row['points'];
}
echo $totalgrade;
```